# Create "Hide/Unhide Slide" keyboard shortcut in Powerpoint for macOS

Tags: macos, powerpoint, keyboard-shortcuts, settings, slideshow

I need to be able to hide/unhide slides quickly (to customize a massive slide deck for different occasions).

Clicking on each slide in the sidebar to hide/unhide it is too tedious.

There seems to be a built-in shortcut to hide slide (command + option + h), but it doesn't work to unhide it. For efficiency, it'd be ideal for **one keyboard shortcut to toggle the Hide/Unhide Slide function(s)**.

Adding a "Hide/Unhide Slide" shortcut to macOS Settings (for Powerpoint) didn't seem to work for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Aha! Mapping "Hide Slide" and "Unhide Slide" to one keyboard shortcuts (**separately**) allowed me to toggle slides from hidden to unhidden with **one shortcut** (In macOS Ventura).

[image]